# What are these very small red bugs on my black walnut tree?

Tags: identification, trees, insects, walnut

This is a black walnut tree. My brother noticed them while we were in the backyard. I have other trees that are not black walnut and do not see these bugs on them.

They are red with a black head. Their bodies have ridges on them. It's hard to tell because they are so small. Closer to a large grain of salt, or small piece of rice.

[image: Mystery bug]

Update: This is from Northeastern Oklahoma area. They have since disappeared. I'm not sure if the heat got to them or they turned into something else or what.

Comment: Its impossible to tell if these creatures have legs or not or whether they're larvae -  do they and if so, how many? Is the tree healthy - there seems to be quite a lot of loose bark?

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark...Scarlet Malachite Beetle larvae.  The size wasn't specified but red larvae with black head should be rare...ish? [Scarlet Malachite](https://www.flickr.com/photos/infinite-regression/5592797189/)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you told us where you are situated.
However, they are likely to be cardinal beetles, possibly larvae feeding under the tree bark.
Totally harmless
[cardinal beetles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_beetle)

Answer (score 0):

Although I think stormy has a point about the odds of finding more red larva with black heads, I discovered another larva possibility: [the walnut caterpillar](http://entoweb.okstate.edu/ddd/insects/walnutdatana.htm) (Datana integerrima), which seems to be a considerable walnut pest; so, I thought it might be likely.